# Error from too many variables in C programing

Tags: c, variables

I want to make the arithmetic mean of positive and negative numbers, the user giving the numbers. I thought to put 2 more variables that counts how many numbers have been summed in the positive and negative side, then doing the arithmetic mean.

But when I put them `int x=0, q=0;` the program is stops from working without any error from the compiler. Why?

[image: the error I get]

```
int total, i, numere[total], negativeSum = 0, positiveSum = 0;

printf("The number of digits you want to calculate the arithmetic amount: : ");
scanf("%d",&total);

for(i=0; i<total; i++){
    printf("Enter number %d : ",(i+1));
    scanf("%d",&numere[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<total ; i++){
   if(numere[i] < 0){
     negativeSum += numere[i];
            }else{
     positiveSum += numere[i];
   }
}
```

Comment: The compiler never gives a run-time error when running the program.

Comment: What is `total` value here in `numere[total]` ? scan the `total` value first and then declare like `int numere[total];`. Also that works if it supports VLA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to know the value of total before allocating memory using the statement numere[total].

As you ask the user input for value of total an alternate approach can be using malloc.

```
int total, i, *numere, negativeSum = 0, positiveSum = 0;

printf("The number of digits you want to calculate the arithmetic amount: : ");
scanf("%d",&total);

numere = malloc(sizeof(int) * total);

for(i=0; i<total; i++){
    printf("Enter number %d : ",(i+1));
    scanf("%d",&numere[i]);
}

for(i=0; i<total ; i++){
   if(numere[i] < 0){
     negativeSum += numere[i];
            }else{
     positiveSum += numere[i];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your sequence of statements

```
int total, i, numere[total], negativeSum = 0, positiveSum = 0;

printf("The number of digits you want to calculate the arithmetic amount: : ");
scanf("%d",&total);
```

`total` is stil uninitialized and so `numere[total]` is undefined. The compiler may remove it altogether. In order to have `total`initialized to define `numere`, you must declare it after you have read `total`:

```
int total, i, negativeSum = 0, positiveSum = 0;

printf("The number of digits you want to calculate the arithmetic amount: : ");
scanf("%d",&total);

int numere[total]; // now it is well-defined.
```